# System.Net.Http DLL not copied into bin folder - IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation

Tags: c#, dll, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a API project that uses .net core project using full .net 4.6.1 I was updating one of my nuget packages that uses Identity Server 4 and was making sure it was not conflicting with some of my old code so I deleted the bin folder content.

I rebuild the project and its now unable to inject my nuget package saying it can't find system.net.http 4.1.1.0. After many hours of slowly ruling things out it turns out that when the project rebuilt and put all its DLLs into the bin folder it did not copy the system.net.http DLL.

What is odd is when I create a new .net core API project using .net 4.6.1 and delete the bin folder and rebuild it does copy the system.net.http dll.

So my question is - how do I make sure the DLL is copied into the bin folder so this does not happen to someone else working on the project?

---

**Update 2017-03-03 11:00**

So I have found out what is breaking my project but I cant work out why / how to fix it.

1) If you create a blank .net core API project change it to use .net461 clean your bin folder and build it you will see the System.Net.Http DLL within the folder "bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64".

2) Now add IdentityServer4 AccessTokenValidation to the dependencies

```
 "IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation": "1.0.5"
```

3) Clear your bin folder again

4) Build project and you will see the System.Net.Http DLL is missing.

The project should still work when you run it but I am using a nuget package that needs that missing DLL...

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I found VS 2017 RC to be buggy and faced some issues of the same kind where things involving nuget did work for some projects and didnt for others

Answer (score 4):

System.Net.Http should be a reference in the project that uses it. Get the reference's properties and set the property "Copy Local" to true.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the options you did didn't work, please try restarting (close / open as "admin") your visual studio, then clean / rebuild. This has fixed my problem.